# I can't capture frames from camera in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I am trying to detect eyes but I have another problem. I cannot display the camera frame. The problem can be obvious but I am newbie. A part of my code below:

Here is my EyeDetection.h

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

using namespace cv;

class EyeDetection {
private:
    CascadeClassifier eye_cascade, eyepair_cascade;
public:
    EyeDetection();
    void detect();
};
```

Here is my EyeDetection.cpp

```
#include "EyeDetection.h"

EyeDetection::EyeDetection() {
    eye_cascade.load("haarcascade_eye.xml");
    eyepair_cascade.load("haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml");
}

void EyeDetection::detect()
{
    VideoCapture webcam(1); //Webcam number is 1
    if (eyepair_cascade.empty() || eye_cascade.empty() || !(webcam).isOpened())
        return;

    webcam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800);
    webcam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600);

    Mat frame;
    while (1) {
        webcam >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) continue;
        imshow("asad", frame);
    }
}
```

And here is my Source.cpp(main):

```
#include "EyeDetection.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    EyeDetection e = EyeDetection();
    e.detect();
    return 0;
}
```

It does not show the camera frame, it shows just a blank gray window. 
What is the problem?

Comment: `imshow` without `waitKey`. Read [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow)! "This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, I forgot waitKey() function. But I had other problems. Because, I had extra lines which I didn't put my question. Those lines are `webcam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800);` and `webcam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600);` I edited the question. When I delete those lines and put waitKey() function on my code, it works. Also, it is interesting but if (width, height)=(320,240), those lines are not problematic and the code works. Actually, I did not understand why.

Comment: Are you saying that when you set the frame size to 800x600, you only keep getting empty frames? What sort of camera?

Comment: Yes, I set the frame size 800x600. I tried my own laptop's cam and another webcam(8 mp and no idea about it's brand). I guess, their resolutions are not enough. But it was working when I did my all job in the main method.

Answer (score -2):

1. Please check your camera id 1.
   If you have only one connected camera then please replace the camera id 0 instead 1.

`cv2.VideoCapture(1)` to `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

2. add the waitKey() line
   add this line at the end of loop

`

```
while (1) {
        webcam >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) continue;
        imshow("asad", frame);
        cv2.waitkey(0)
    }
```

`
Maybe to check about waitKey() should be needed for you.
Thanks.

Comment: please modify your answer. remove "cv2."s. and perhaps waitkey(10) not waitkey(0)

Comment: What language is that supposed to be? So far it looks like some weird jumble of Python and C++, which won't work in either.

Comment: That was the python script.